# Paste not working for long strings?

Tags: r, paste

I cannot for the life of me figure out why paste with collapse="\n" won't work for me, for just this line (it works in other parts of the code).

Perhaps a character limit with the paste function?

(I have trimmed leading and lagging white space)

Below you will notice that paste does not in fact insert \n between the two long strings:

```
> MM
[1] "F1_all =~ target\nF2_all =~ target\nF3_all =~ target\nF4_all =~ target\nF5_all =~ target\nF6_all =~ target"
> regsflat
[1] "F1_all ~ 1*F1_0351 + 1*F1_0354 + 1*F1_0414 + 1*F1_0415 + 1*F1_0420 + 1*F1_0430 + 1*F1_0464 + 1*F1_0484 + 1*F1_0488 + 1*F1_0496 + 1*F1_0508 + 1*F1_0517 + 1*F1_0527 + 1*F1_0592 + 1*F1_0593 + 1*F1_0596 + 1*F1_0609 + 1*F1_0640 + 1*F1_0646 + 1*F1_0647 + 1*F1_0683 + 1*F1_0686 + 1*F1_0691 + 1*F1_0696 + 1*F1_0713 + 1*F1_0715 + 1*F1_0717 + 1*F1_0757 + 1*F1_0759 + 1*F1_0764 + 1*F1_0765 + 1*F1_0771 + 1*F1_0772 + 1*F1_0775 + 1*F1_0776 + 1*F1_0778 + 1*F1_0781 + 1*F1_0793 + 1*F1_0796 + 1*F1_0797 + 1*F1_0799 + 1*F1_0842 + 1*F1_0843 + 1*F1_0845 + 1*F1_0865 + 1*F1_0879 + 1*F1_0895 + 1*F1_0936 + 1*F1_1544 + 1*F1_1545 + 1*F1_1802 + 1*F1_1803 + 1*F1_1804 + 1*F1_1805 + 1*F1_1806 + 1*F1_1807 + 1*F1_1809 + 1*F1_1815 + 1*F1_2261 + 1*F1_2262 + 1*F1_2353 + 1*F1_2354 + 1*F1_2435 + 1*F1_BBRM1WA + 1*F1_BBRM2WA + 1*F1_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F1_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F1_CBWASOUTH + 1*F1_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF2_all ~ 1*F2_0351 + 1*F2_0354 + 1*F2_0414 + 1*F2_0415 + 1*F2_0420 + 1*F2_0430 + 1*F2_0464 + 1*F2_0484 + 1*F2_0488 + 1*F2_0496 + 1*F2_0508 + 1*F2_0517 + 1*F2_0527 + 1*F2_0592 + 1*F2_0593 + 1*F2_0596 + 1*F2_0609 + 1*F2_0640 + 1*F2_0646 + 1*F2_0647 + 1*F2_0683 + 1*F2_0686 + 1*F2_0691 + 1*F2_0696 + 1*F2_0713 + 1*F2_0715 + 1*F2_0717 + 1*F2_0757 + 1*F2_0759 + 1*F2_0764 + 1*F2_0765 + 1*F2_0771 + 1*F2_0772 + 1*F2_0775 + 1*F2_0776 + 1*F2_0778 + 1*F2_0781 + 1*F2_0793 + 1*F2_0796 + 1*F2_0797 + 1*F2_0799 + 1*F2_0842 + 1*F2_0843 + 1*F2_0845 + 1*F2_0865 + 1*F2_0879 + 1*F2_0895 + 1*F2_0936 + 1*F2_1544 + 1*F2_1545 + 1*F2_1802 + 1*F2_1803 + 1*F2_1804 + 1*F2_1805 + 1*F2_1806 + 1*F2_1807 + 1*F2_1809 + 1*F2_1815 + 1*F2_2261 + 1*F2_2262 + 1*F2_2353 + 1*F2_2354 + 1*F2_2435 + 1*F2_BBRM1WA + 1*F2_BBRM2WA + 1*F2_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F2_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F2_CBWASOUTH + 1*F2_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF3_all ~ 1*F3_0351 + 1*F3_0354 + 1*F3_0414 + 1*F3_0415 + 1*F3_0420 + 1*F3_0430 + 1*F3_0464 + 1*F3_0484 + 1*F3_0488 + 1*F3_0496 + 1*F3_0508 + 1*F3_0517 + 1*F3_0527 + 1*F3_0592 + 1*F3_0593 + 1*F3_0596 + 1*F3_0609 + 1*F3_0640 + 1*F3_0646 + 1*F3_0647 + 1*F3_0683 + 1*F3_0686 + 1*F3_0691 + 1*F3_0696 + 1*F3_0713 + 1*F3_0715 + 1*F3_0717 + 1*F3_0757 + 1*F3_0759 + 1*F3_0764 + 1*F3_0765 + 1*F3_0771 + 1*F3_0772 + 1*F3_0775 + 1*F3_0776 + 1*F3_0778 + 1*F3_0781 + 1*F3_0793 + 1*F3_0796 + 1*F3_0797 + 1*F3_0799 + 1*F3_0842 + 1*F3_0843 + 1*F3_0845 + 1*F3_0865 + 1*F3_0879 + 1*F3_0895 + 1*F3_0936 + 1*F3_1544 + 1*F3_1545 + 1*F3_1802 + 1*F3_1803 + 1*F3_1804 + 1*F3_1805 + 1*F3_1806 + 1*F3_1807 + 1*F3_1809 + 1*F3_1815 + 1*F3_2261 + 1*F3_2262 + 1*F3_2353 + 1*F3_2354 + 1*F3_2435 + 1*F3_BBRM1WA + 1*F3_BBRM2WA + 1*F3_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F3_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F3_CBWASOUTH + 1*F3_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF4_all ~ 1*F4_0351 + 1*F4_0354 + 1*F4_0414 + 1*F4_0415 + 1*F4_0420 + 1*F4_0430 + 1*F4_0464 + 1*F4_0484 + 1*F4_0488 + 1*F4_0496 + 1*F4_0508 + 1*F4_0517 + 1*F4_0527 + 1*F4_0592 + 1*F4_0593 + 1*F4_0596 + 1*F4_0609 + 1*F4_0640 + 1*F4_0646 + 1*F4_0647 + 1*F4_0683 + 1*F4_0686 + 1*F4_0691 + 1*F4_0696 + 1*F4_0713 + 1*F4_0715 + 1*F4_0717 + 1*F4_0757 + 1*F4_0759 + 1*F4_0764 + 1*F4_0765 + 1*F4_0771 + 1*F4_0772 + 1*F4_0775 + 1*F4_0776 + 1*F4_0778 + 1*F4_0781 + 1*F4_0793 + 1*F4_0796 + 1*F4_0797 + 1*F4_0799 + 1*F4_0842 + 1*F4_0843 + 1*F4_0845 + 1*F4_0865 + 1*F4_0879 + 1*F4_0895 + 1*F4_0936 + 1*F4_1544 + 1*F4_1545 + 1*F4_1802 + 1*F4_1803 + 1*F4_1804 + 1*F4_1805 + 1*F4_1806 + 1*F4_1807 + 1*F4_1809 + 1*F4_1815 + 1*F4_2261 + 1*F4_2262 + 1*F4_2353 + 1*F4_2354 + 1*F4_2435 + 1*F4_BBRM1WA + 1*F4_BBRM2WA + 1*F4_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F4_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F4_CBWASOUTH + 1*F4_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF5_all ~ 1*F5_0351 + 1*F5_0354 + 1*F5_0414 + 1*F5_0415 + 1*F5_0420 + 1*F5_0430 + 1*F5_0464 + 1*F5_0484 + 1*F5_0488 + 1*F5_0496 + 1*F5_0508 + 1*F5_0517 + 1*F5_0527 + 1*F5_0592 + 1*F5_0593 + 1*F5_0596 + 1*F5_0609 + 1*F5_0640 + 1*F5_0646 + 1*F5_0647 + 1*F5_0683 + 1*F5_0686 + 1*F5_0691 + 1*F5_0696 + 1*F5_0713 + 1*F5_0715 + 1*F5_0717 + 1*F5_0757 + 1*F5_0759 + 1*F5_0764 + 1*F5_0765 + 1*F5_0771 + 1*F5_0772 + 1*F5_0775 + 1*F5_0776 + 1*F5_0778 + 1*F5_0781 + 1*F5_0793 + 1*F5_0796 + 1*F5_0797 + 1*F5_0799 + 1*F5_0842 + 1*F5_0843 + 1*F5_0845 + 1*F5_0865 + 1*F5_0879 + 1*F5_0895 + 1*F5_0936 + 1*F5_1544 + 1*F5_1545 + 1*F5_1802 + 1*F5_1803 + 1*F5_1804 + 1*F5_1805 + 1*F5_1806 + 1*F5_1807 + 1*F5_1809 + 1*F5_1815 + 1*F5_2261 + 1*F5_2262 + 1*F5_2353 + 1*F5_2354 + 1*F5_2435 + 1*F5_BBRM1WA + 1*F5_BBRM2WA + 1*F5_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F5_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F5_CBWASOUTH + 1*F5_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF6_all ~ 1*F6_0351 + 1*F6_0354 + 1*F6_0414 + 1*F6_0415 + 1*F6_0420 + 1*F6_0430 + 1*F6_0464 + 1*F6_0484 + 1*F6_0488 + 1*F6_0496 + 1*F6_0508 + 1*F6_0517 + 1*F6_0527 + 1*F6_0592 + 1*F6_0593 + 1*F6_0596 + 1*F6_0609 + 1*F6_0640 + 1*F6_0646 + 1*F6_0647 + 1*F6_0683 + 1*F6_0686 + 1*F6_0691 + 1*F6_0696 + 1*F6_0713 + 1*F6_0715 + 1*F6_0717 + 1*F6_0757 + 1*F6_0759 + 1*F6_0764 + 1*F6_0765 + 1*F6_0771 + 1*F6_0772 + 1*F6_0775 + 1*F6_0776 + 1*F6_0778 + 1*F6_0781 + 1*F6_0793 + 1*F6_0796 + 1*F6_0797 + 1*F6_0799 + 1*F6_0842 + 1*F6_0843 + 1*F6_0845 + 1*F6_0865 + 1*F6_0879 + 1*F6_0895 + 1*F6_0936 + 1*F6_1544 + 1*F6_1545 + 1*F6_1802 + 1*F6_1803 + 1*F6_1804 + 1*F6_1805 + 1*F6_1806 + 1*F6_1807 + 1*F6_1809 + 1*F6_1815 + 1*F6_2261 + 1*F6_2262 + 1*F6_2353 + 1*F6_2354 + 1*F6_2435 + 1*F6_BBRM1WA + 1*F6_BBRM2WA + 1*F6_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F6_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F6_CBWASOUTH + 1*F6_R&R-WESTCOAST"
> paste(MM, regsflat, collapse="\n")
[1] "F1_all =~ target\nF2_all =~ target\nF3_all =~ target\nF4_all =~ target\nF5_all =~ target\nF6_all =~ target F1_all ~ 1*F1_0351 + 1*F1_0354 + 1*F1_0414 + 1*F1_0415 + 1*F1_0420 + 1*F1_0430 + 1*F1_0464 + 1*F1_0484 + 1*F1_0488 + 1*F1_0496 + 1*F1_0508 + 1*F1_0517 + 1*F1_0527 + 1*F1_0592 + 1*F1_0593 + 1*F1_0596 + 1*F1_0609 + 1*F1_0640 + 1*F1_0646 + 1*F1_0647 + 1*F1_0683 + 1*F1_0686 + 1*F1_0691 + 1*F1_0696 + 1*F1_0713 + 1*F1_0715 + 1*F1_0717 + 1*F1_0757 + 1*F1_0759 + 1*F1_0764 + 1*F1_0765 + 1*F1_0771 + 1*F1_0772 + 1*F1_0775 + 1*F1_0776 + 1*F1_0778 + 1*F1_0781 + 1*F1_0793 + 1*F1_0796 + 1*F1_0797 + 1*F1_0799 + 1*F1_0842 + 1*F1_0843 + 1*F1_0845 + 1*F1_0865 + 1*F1_0879 + 1*F1_0895 + 1*F1_0936 + 1*F1_1544 + 1*F1_1545 + 1*F1_1802 + 1*F1_1803 + 1*F1_1804 + 1*F1_1805 + 1*F1_1806 + 1*F1_1807 + 1*F1_1809 + 1*F1_1815 + 1*F1_2261 + 1*F1_2262 + 1*F1_2353 + 1*F1_2354 + 1*F1_2435 + 1*F1_BBRM1WA + 1*F1_BBRM2WA + 1*F1_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F1_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F1_CBWASOUTH + 1*F1_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF2_all ~ 1*F2_0351 + 1*F2_0354 + 1*F2_0414 + 1*F2_0415 + 1*F2_0420 + 1*F2_0430 + 1*F2_0464 + 1*F2_0484 + 1*F2_0488 + 1*F2_0496 + 1*F2_0508 + 1*F2_0517 + 1*F2_0527 + 1*F2_0592 + 1*F2_0593 + 1*F2_0596 + 1*F2_0609 + 1*F2_0640 + 1*F2_0646 + 1*F2_0647 + 1*F2_0683 + 1*F2_0686 + 1*F2_0691 + 1*F2_0696 + 1*F2_0713 + 1*F2_0715 + 1*F2_0717 + 1*F2_0757 + 1*F2_0759 + 1*F2_0764 + 1*F2_0765 + 1*F2_0771 + 1*F2_0772 + 1*F2_0775 + 1*F2_0776 + 1*F2_0778 + 1*F2_0781 + 1*F2_0793 + 1*F2_0796 + 1*F2_0797 + 1*F2_0799 + 1*F2_0842 + 1*F2_0843 + 1*F2_0845 + 1*F2_0865 + 1*F2_0879 + 1*F2_0895 + 1*F2_0936 + 1*F2_1544 + 1*F2_1545 + 1*F2_1802 + 1*F2_1803 + 1*F2_1804 + 1*F2_1805 + 1*F2_1806 + 1*F2_1807 + 1*F2_1809 + 1*F2_1815 + 1*F2_2261 + 1*F2_2262 + 1*F2_2353 + 1*F2_2354 + 1*F2_2435 + 1*F2_BBRM1WA + 1*F2_BBRM2WA + 1*F2_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F2_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F2_CBWASOUTH + 1*F2_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF3_all ~ 1*F3_0351 + 1*F3_0354 + 1*F3_0414 + 1*F3_0415 + 1*F3_0420 + 1*F3_0430 + 1*F3_0464 + 1*F3_0484 + 1*F3_0488 + 1*F3_0496 + 1*F3_0508 + 1*F3_0517 + 1*F3_0527 + 1*F3_0592 + 1*F3_0593 + 1*F3_0596 + 1*F3_0609 + 1*F3_0640 + 1*F3_0646 + 1*F3_0647 + 1*F3_0683 + 1*F3_0686 + 1*F3_0691 + 1*F3_0696 + 1*F3_0713 + 1*F3_0715 + 1*F3_0717 + 1*F3_0757 + 1*F3_0759 + 1*F3_0764 + 1*F3_0765 + 1*F3_0771 + 1*F3_0772 + 1*F3_0775 + 1*F3_0776 + 1*F3_0778 + 1*F3_0781 + 1*F3_0793 + 1*F3_0796 + 1*F3_0797 + 1*F3_0799 + 1*F3_0842 + 1*F3_0843 + 1*F3_0845 + 1*F3_0865 + 1*F3_0879 + 1*F3_0895 + 1*F3_0936 + 1*F3_1544 + 1*F3_1545 + 1*F3_1802 + 1*F3_1803 + 1*F3_1804 + 1*F3_1805 + 1*F3_1806 + 1*F3_1807 + 1*F3_1809 + 1*F3_1815 + 1*F3_2261 + 1*F3_2262 + 1*F3_2353 + 1*F3_2354 + 1*F3_2435 + 1*F3_BBRM1WA + 1*F3_BBRM2WA + 1*F3_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F3_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F3_CBWASOUTH + 1*F3_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF4_all ~ 1*F4_0351 + 1*F4_0354 + 1*F4_0414 + 1*F4_0415 + 1*F4_0420 + 1*F4_0430 + 1*F4_0464 + 1*F4_0484 + 1*F4_0488 + 1*F4_0496 + 1*F4_0508 + 1*F4_0517 + 1*F4_0527 + 1*F4_0592 + 1*F4_0593 + 1*F4_0596 + 1*F4_0609 + 1*F4_0640 + 1*F4_0646 + 1*F4_0647 + 1*F4_0683 + 1*F4_0686 + 1*F4_0691 + 1*F4_0696 + 1*F4_0713 + 1*F4_0715 + 1*F4_0717 + 1*F4_0757 + 1*F4_0759 + 1*F4_0764 + 1*F4_0765 + 1*F4_0771 + 1*F4_0772 + 1*F4_0775 + 1*F4_0776 + 1*F4_0778 + 1*F4_0781 + 1*F4_0793 + 1*F4_0796 + 1*F4_0797 + 1*F4_0799 + 1*F4_0842 + 1*F4_0843 + 1*F4_0845 + 1*F4_0865 + 1*F4_0879 + 1*F4_0895 + 1*F4_0936 + 1*F4_1544 + 1*F4_1545 + 1*F4_1802 + 1*F4_1803 + 1*F4_1804 + 1*F4_1805 + 1*F4_1806 + 1*F4_1807 + 1*F4_1809 + 1*F4_1815 + 1*F4_2261 + 1*F4_2262 + 1*F4_2353 + 1*F4_2354 + 1*F4_2435 + 1*F4_BBRM1WA + 1*F4_BBRM2WA + 1*F4_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F4_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F4_CBWASOUTH + 1*F4_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF5_all ~ 1*F5_0351 + 1*F5_0354 + 1*F5_0414 + 1*F5_0415 + 1*F5_0420 + 1*F5_0430 + 1*F5_0464 + 1*F5_0484 + 1*F5_0488 + 1*F5_0496 + 1*F5_0508 + 1*F5_0517 + 1*F5_0527 + 1*F5_0592 + 1*F5_0593 + 1*F5_0596 + 1*F5_0609 + 1*F5_0640 + 1*F5_0646 + 1*F5_0647 + 1*F5_0683 + 1*F5_0686 + 1*F5_0691 + 1*F5_0696 + 1*F5_0713 + 1*F5_0715 + 1*F5_0717 + 1*F5_0757 + 1*F5_0759 + 1*F5_0764 + 1*F5_0765 + 1*F5_0771 + 1*F5_0772 + 1*F5_0775 + 1*F5_0776 + 1*F5_0778 + 1*F5_0781 + 1*F5_0793 + 1*F5_0796 + 1*F5_0797 + 1*F5_0799 + 1*F5_0842 + 1*F5_0843 + 1*F5_0845 + 1*F5_0865 + 1*F5_0879 + 1*F5_0895 + 1*F5_0936 + 1*F5_1544 + 1*F5_1545 + 1*F5_1802 + 1*F5_1803 + 1*F5_1804 + 1*F5_1805 + 1*F5_1806 + 1*F5_1807 + 1*F5_1809 + 1*F5_1815 + 1*F5_2261 + 1*F5_2262 + 1*F5_2353 + 1*F5_2354 + 1*F5_2435 + 1*F5_BBRM1WA + 1*F5_BBRM2WA + 1*F5_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F5_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F5_CBWASOUTH + 1*F5_R&R-WESTCOAST\nF6_all ~ 1*F6_0351 + 1*F6_0354 + 1*F6_0414 + 1*F6_0415 + 1*F6_0420 + 1*F6_0430 + 1*F6_0464 + 1*F6_0484 + 1*F6_0488 + 1*F6_0496 + 1*F6_0508 + 1*F6_0517 + 1*F6_0527 + 1*F6_0592 + 1*F6_0593 + 1*F6_0596 + 1*F6_0609 + 1*F6_0640 + 1*F6_0646 + 1*F6_0647 + 1*F6_0683 + 1*F6_0686 + 1*F6_0691 + 1*F6_0696 + 1*F6_0713 + 1*F6_0715 + 1*F6_0717 + 1*F6_0757 + 1*F6_0759 + 1*F6_0764 + 1*F6_0765 + 1*F6_0771 + 1*F6_0772 + 1*F6_0775 + 1*F6_0776 + 1*F6_0778 + 1*F6_0781 + 1*F6_0793 + 1*F6_0796 + 1*F6_0797 + 1*F6_0799 + 1*F6_0842 + 1*F6_0843 + 1*F6_0845 + 1*F6_0865 + 1*F6_0879 + 1*F6_0895 + 1*F6_0936 + 1*F6_1544 + 1*F6_1545 + 1*F6_1802 + 1*F6_1803 + 1*F6_1804 + 1*F6_1805 + 1*F6_1806 + 1*F6_1807 + 1*F6_1809 + 1*F6_1815 + 1*F6_2261 + 1*F6_2262 + 1*F6_2353 + 1*F6_2354 + 1*F6_2435 + 1*F6_BBRM1WA + 1*F6_BBRM2WA + 1*F6_BUSINESSBANKWA + 1*F6_CBWACENTRAL + 1*F6_CBWASOUTH + 1*F6_R&R-WESTCOAST"
>
```

Comment: That's because you need `sep`, not `collapse` as a `paste` argument.

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
paste(MM, regsflat, sep="\n")
```